# How to use voicechat on Fortnite Mobile?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale, mobile

I recently was playing mobile Fornite on my iPhone with a friend and wanted to use voice comms/voice chat, but I was unsure how.

How do I use Fortnite team chat on mobile iOS?

Comment: Is there an option in settings (Settings>Sound>Voice Chat On)? If so, im pretty sure if you have a mic and you speak, he will be able to hear you. There is no Push-to-talk like on PC

Comment: It's coming soon. Maybe use Discord or any other app in the meantime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not yet implemented but will be coming soon:

> **VOICE CHAT**
>
> We know that communication is key when you’re squadding up for that Victory Royale, so we’re working to bring voice chat to mobile. On top of that, you’ll be able to chat with your teammates regardless of platform!
>
> We’re also looking to make it really easy to mute yourself, other players, or open up all communications with a simple tap. There will be a button on the screen that lets you mute yourself, mute everyone in your party, or go back to open-microphone.

Source: https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/news/state-of-mobile